# How to pass data to shortened constructor invocation in Koin

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I would like to get rid of multiple `get()` in Koin module definition in my code.

I have a few module definitions like this (of course this one is simplified and has dummy naming just for preview purposes):

```
val testModule = module {
    viewModel {
        TestViewModel(get(), get(), get(), testValue = true /* some external data */)
    }
}
```

And `TestViewModel` is like this:

```
class TestViewModel(
    dep1: Application,
    dep2: Application,
    dep3: Application,
    testValue: Boolean,
) : ViewModel()
```

I am aware of methods like:

```
val testModule = module {
    viewModel {
        new(::TestViewModel)
    }
}
```

and:

```
val testModule = module {
    viewModelOf(::TestViewModel)
}
```

But I haven't found a way to pass a value for `testValue` in my constructor.